# Lie Algebra of U(N) and SO(N)

Tags: group-theory

U(N) and SO(N) are quite important groups in physics. I thought I would find this with an easy google search. Apparently NOT! What is the Lie algebra and Lie bracket of the two groups?

Comment: If you have a copy of John Lee's book on Smooth manifolds, you can find the important details of these computations in chapter 8.  I don't have my book with me right now, but I'll update with specific page information tomorrow.

Comment: p.203-204 in the book mentioned above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Lie algebra for $U(N)$ consists of $N\times N$ skew-Hermitian matrices, and the Lie algebra for $SO(N)$ consists of $N\times N$ skew-symmetric matrices.  In both cases, the Lie bracket is given by the ordinary commutator $[A,B] = AB-BA$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Owen Biesel gives the standard definition.

But if you want to see a definition in terms of generators and relations you must choose a basis and then express the commutators of that basis in terns of the basis. Usually, a Chevalley basis is used, which consists of the generators of a Cartan (= maximal commutative) subalgebra and an associated root system. See 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley_basis

You may wish to check check that for $U(2)$, this gives the familiar definition in terms of angular momentum.